# Correct hyphenation in compound adjective

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I want to rephrase

> The costs they compute are weighted by time intervals.

by

> They compute time interval-weighted costs.

The question is, what is the correct hyphenation?

> time interval weighted
> time interval-weighted
> time-interval weighted
> time-interval-weighted

Comment: Hello, 469. What does a quick Google search for "time interval weighted" strongly suggest as the usual variant? Is the unhyphenated variant used at all? But trumping normal usage, one should avoid anything that might mislead the odd reader (I don't think any of your suggestions does) or looks distinctly odd (2?). Some might even suggest << time-interval–weighted >> (the hyphen showing the closer cohesiveness, the dash the looser.) There are different style choices.

Comment: *They compute time-weighted costs.* (Time already comes in intervals.)

Comment: @TinfoilHat Time-weighted could also refer to time of day, e.g. prime time is given more weight than off hours.